# Why do my dog's ears feel warm?

Tags: dogs, health, digestion

My dog has been experiencing some digestive track issues and I noticed that her ears are warm to the touch. Does this indicate she may have a fever?

Answer (score 2):

It could be an indication of a fever, or it could be a sign of some other medical problem, such as an ear infection. It is probably a good idea to get your dog checked out by a vet.